# One Model, two different views - PySide

Tags: python, qtableview, qlistview, qabstracttablemodel, pyside2

I have QAbstractTableModel with 4 columns.

I'm trying to display the first 3 columns on a view (QTableView), and when a row is selected on such view a second view (a QListView) should display the 4th column of the model.

I found something about a QProxyModel, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind on it. Also there are a 'solutions' I found something similar [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901069/when-single-model-is-shared-by-multiple-views) but somehow I want the inverse result.

The data I'm trying to dispaly is something like this: [['green', 'car', 'available',['a','b','c','d']]]

So, on the Table View it would show:  green - car - available. 
And when clicking on such row, the List view would display the array on the last position:  a - b - c - d.

I hope it makes sense.

Tips on directions, documentations, examples?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular case, using a proxy model is not appropriate, what should be done each time you click is to obtain the `QModelIndex`, with the `QModelIndex` we obtain the model and the row pressed so that at the end we obtain the saved list, this list we can pass it as a source to the model `QStringListModel` and we will establish this in the `QListView`. To hide the column we use `hideColumn()` of the `QTableView`.

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.values = [['green', 'car', 'available', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']],
                       ['red', 'airplane', 'available', ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']],
                       ['yellow', 'boat', 'not available', ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']]]

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 4

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.values)

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if 0 <= index.row() < self.rowCount() and 0 <= index.column() < self.columnCount():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return self.values[index.row()][index.column()]


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        splitter = QSplitter()
        self.tv = QTableView()
        self.lv = QListView()
        self.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
        splitter.addWidget(self.tv)
        splitter.addWidget(self.lv)
        self.layout().addWidget(splitter)
        model = TableModel()
        self.tv.setModel(model)
        self.tv.hideColumn(3)

        self.tv.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

    def on_clicked(self, ix):
        model = ix.model()
        m_list = model.index(ix.row(), 3).data()
        self.lv.setModel(QStringListModel(m_list))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Man! You again! Thank you for such a great answer. Upvoted.

Comment: sorry to bother you, but your help has been great. Could you point me in the direction of how to construct a ItemDelegate that is just a square of color that when clicked allows me to choose the color it will display?  I'm trying to understand the Paint method but it seems, literally, coded... hard to get a start on this. ... Well, anyways, thank you.